# How can I escape characters when creating a csv file in Data fusion?

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am creating a pipeline in google data fusion that should read records from a source database and write them to a target csv file in Cloud Storage.

The problem is that in the resulting file the separator character is a comma ",", and some fields are of type string and contains phrases with commas, so when I try to load the resulting file in wrangler as a csv, I get an error, because the number of fields in the csv does not match the number of fields in the schema (because of fields containing comma strings).

How can I escape these special characters in the pipeline?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the data as TSV instead of CSV (set the format of the sink plugin to `tsv`). Then load the data as `tsv` in Wrangler.